# How can I display line numbers in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ IDEA, how can I display the line numbers?  I'd like to see what specific line I'm coding on.

Comment: Ctrl + G gives you the current line, and allows you to navigate to other lines.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from here: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/intellij/displaying-line-numbers

> Select Tools | IDE Options
>
> Select Editor
>
> In the Display group, click Show line numbers
>
> When you're finished here, click OK

You also may find [this keyboard shortcut list](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) useful. `CTRL+G` displays the current line, and also allows you to jump to a specified line number.

Answer (score 1):

in Intellij Ultimate 2016, it's View/Active Editor/Show Line Numbers

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ 2016 for permanent line numbers: from Preferences do:
Editor->General->Appearance Show Line Numbers